# I tried to use maven in cmd, but I don't get the generated .jar file in the specified location

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I used `mvn clean package -DoutputDirectory=<my path>`, but I don't get compiled .jar file in my listed output directory via command prompt, does anyone knows, how to fix it in the cmd?

Here's my debug configuration from Intellij IDEA Community:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XMaF.png

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Just out of curiosity, why can't you compile it normally and then copy the file afterwards, i.e. with `mv` or `cp`?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to automate the process of testing my plugin in Minecraft, so here's my debug configuration:
https://i.imgur.com/KDnLYDV.png
I use Intellij IDEA Community

Comment: @vatbub, can you explain the best way of this?

Comment: Well, run Maven without `-DoutputDirectory` (e.g. `mvn clean package`) and afterwards run `cp target/my-artifact.jar <my path>` (if you're on Linux) or `copy target\my-artifact.jar <my path>` (if you're on Windows)